# How to do Protractor Testing for ui-view or ng-if?

Tags: testing, protractor

I am trying to use protractor testing for my website. When I run the test, Firefox displays "Welcome home soldier" which is the part from `ng-view="admin"` (correct view) in the screen. However the test results as failed.

index.html:

```
<div ui-view="!admin">
 <h1> Please sign up </h1> 
</div>

<div ui-view="admin">
 <h1> Welcome home soldier </h1> 
</div>
```

index_spec.js:

If I do this then the test fails:

```
expect($('[ui-view="admin"]').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

If I do this then the test success:

```
expect($('[ui-view="admin"]').isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
```

I have tried to do `isPresent()`, but it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If try this, do you get the good result ?

```
browser.wait(function () {
    return $('[ui-view="admin"]').isDisplayed();
}, 5000);
expect($('[ui-view="admin"]').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your HTML or CSS doesn't have the elements as hidden - using `display:none`  or  `display:block`, under which the `isDisplayed()` method would return false. This is as defined by the code for `isDisplayed()` method [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js).

Also, you can check`element.size()!=0` to check if it's displayed (it's not a full proof solution though)